# Missing dependency 'already at newest version'

Tags: package-management, 17.10, qt

I have Ubuntu 17.10 and until yesterday I was able to run the [Digiwage QT wallet](https://coin.digiwage.org/) without any problems. The wallet is just an implementation of the well-know QT wallet used for loads of cryptocurrencies.
Yesterday I did something like `apt autoremove` (I suppose that's the cause of the recent problems) and sice then the wallet, which is started from the command line, is not working:

`~/wallets/digiwage-1.1.0/bin$ ./digiwage-qt  ./digiwage-qt: error while loading shared libraries: libX11-xcb.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

When I try to install the missing `libx11-xcb-dev` package I get the following:

`~/wallets/digiwage-1.1.0/bin$ sudo apt-get install libx11-xcb-dev Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree        Reading state information... Done libx11-xcb-dev is already the newest version (2:1.6.4-3). 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.`

So, the package is missing, but also already at the newest version? Is there some internal link missing?
`apt autoremove` and `apt install -f` and the like didn't help.

Comment: 32-bit binary on a 64-bit system? If so, install the 32-bit library: `sudo apt install libx11-xcb1:i386`.